# login openshift with kubadmin fail: Login failed (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: openshift

As per offical documentation by Openshift , we can get kubadmin password as below:

```
crc console --credentials 
To login as a regular user, run 'oc login -u developer -p developer https://api.crc.testing:6443'.
To login as an admin, run 'oc login -u kubeadmin -p gALwE-jY6p9-poc9U-gRcdu https://api.crc.testing:6443'
```

However , I can login successfully with developer/developer .kubeadmin will fail with "Login failed (401 Unauthorized)" . Restart CRC muiltiple times . Still not works ... Any idea about this ?

```
$ oc login -u developer -p developer https://api.crc.testing:6443
Login successful.

You have one project on this server: "demo"

Using project "demo"



$ oc login -u kubeadmin -p gALwE-jY6p9-poc9U-gRcdu https://api.crc.testing:6443
Login failed (401 Unauthorized)
Verify you have provided correct credentials.
```

Any inputs will be appreciated . Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you see anything helpful if you add `--loglevel=6` or --`loglevel=8`?

Comment: I‘ve tried as you mentioned . No error logs found ...    
  `INFO Checking if running as non-root              
  INFO Checking if running inside WSL2`              

   `...`

 `INFO All operators are available. Ensuring stability...INFO Operators are stable (2/3)...                
  INFO Operators are stable (3/3)...                
  INFO Adding crc-admin and crc-developer contexts to kubeconfig...Started the OpenShift    cluster.`

 `......`  

  `$ oc login -u developer https://api.crc.testing:6443`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you restarted CRC.  Have you tried deleting and recreating the cluster?

One of the first steps in productionizing a cluster is to remove the kubeadmin account - is it possible that you've done that and the "crc console --credentials" is now only displaying what it used to be?

If you have another admin account try:

```
$ oc get -n kube-system secret kubeadmin
```

The step to remove that account (see: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/authentication/remove-kubeadmin.html) is to simply delete that secret.  If you've done that at some point in this cluster's history you'll either need to use your other admin accounts in place of kubeadmin, or recreate the CRC instance (crc stop; crc delete; crc setup)

Comment: I restart my crc muiltiple times and now works now ...  

`$ oc login -u kubeadmin -p gALwE-jY6p9-poc9U-gRcdu https://api.crc.testing:6443`
`Login successful.`

The password I typed is the same as before . Not sure why it works this time ...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others are having this issue and the issue persists even after trying crc stop, crc delete, crc cleanup, crc setup, crc start, I was able to sign in as kubeadmin by NOT using the following command after crc start got my CodeReady Container up and running.

```
eval $(crc oc-env)
```

Instead, I issue the crc oc-env command. In this example that the output returns /home/john.doe/.crc/bin/oc.

```
~]$ crc oc-env
export PATH="/home/john.doe/.crc/bin/oc:$PATH"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(crc oc-env)
```

I then list the contents of the /home/john.doe/.crc/bin/oc directory which shows that the /home/john.doe/.crc/bin/oc directory is symbolically linked to the /home/john.doe/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt__amd64/oc file.

```
~]$ ll /home/john.doe/.crc/bin/oc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 john.doe john.doe 61 Jun  8 20:27 oc -> /home/john.doe/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.10.12_amd64/oc
```

And I was then able to sign in using the absolute path to the oc command line tool.

```
~]$ /home/john.doe/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.10.12_amd64/oc login -u kubeadmin -p 28Fwr-Znmfb-V6ySF-zUu29 https://api.crc.testing:6443
Login successful.
```

I'm sure I could dig a bit more into this, checking the contents of my users $PATH, but suffice to say, this at least is a work around for me that gets me to be able to sign in as kubeadmin.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy . Will try if facing the issue next time .  crc stop, crc delete, crc cleanup, crc setup, crc start , is not really a good solution .